# SSH using AD credentials only works for username@domain@x.x.x.x and not username@x.x.x.x

Tags: active-directory, ssh, amazon-linux, realm

I built a new server using Amazon Linux 2023 and I join it to our domain `avengers` using `realmd`.

I am however getting an issue where i can't login to the server with this command `mervin@10.10.10.1` but works if i do `mervin@avengers@10.10.10.1`.

Can someone help please ? i want it to be able to ssh using just the username of the AD account `mervin@10.10.10.1`

Comment: @RomeoNinov It does. Thank you so much

Comment: @RomeoNinov I am able to login using just my username but my home user folder is still being create with the Fully qualified domain as such `/home/username@domain`. Is there a way to prevent this ?

Comment: Please ask new question as this is different topic